# Angular2 RC6 Update

Tags: angular

Since I have updated my package.json to Angular2 RC6 I get errors TS2305:

- "../@angular/router/index" has no exported member 'RouterConfig'
- "../@angular/common/index" has no exported member 'Control', 'ControlGroup','Validators', etc.

My dependencies in package.json are as follows

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.18",
"angular2localization": "^0.10.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"moment": "^2.13.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.17"
```

Comment: They don't exist anymore. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @surfspider did you figure this out?

Comment: Routes replaces RouterConfig, Validators is in @angular/forms and not sure but I think Control, ControlGroup are not needed anymore, you can just use FormsModule and reference it in your app.module.ts that's what I take from the docs, the tutorials are also updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thank you for your answer! After I have replaced RouterConfig with Routes, Control with FormControl, FormModel with FormGroup etc. I can compile without errors.